# Как сделать перенос текста внутри параграфа?

Tags: html, css, текст

Что делать если после того как место для текста заканчивается и он переходит на новую строку отступ не сохраняется?

[image]

```css
body {
    background-color: #202020;
    color:white;
}

.howWeWork img {
  width: 100px;
}
.howWeWork p {
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <title>Temp</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

<div class="howWeWork">

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title-30">Схема работы</h1>
    <p class="subTitle-18">Какой-то непонятный текст</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Dollar_Sign.svg/2048px-Dollar_Sign.svg.png" alt="">
        <p class="title-18-bold ps-4">Заявка</p>
        <small class="ps-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Dollar_Sign.svg/2048px-Dollar_Sign.svg.png" alt="">
        <p class="title-18-bold ps-4">Заявка</p>
        <small class="ps-4 text-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure velit consequuntur rem quos assumenda!</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Dollar_Sign.svg/2048px-Dollar_Sign.svg.png" alt="">
        <p class="title-18-bold ps-4">Заявка</p>
        <small class="ps-4">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Dollar_Sign.svg/2048px-Dollar_Sign.svg.png" alt="">
        <p class="title-18-bold ps-4">Заявка</p>
        <small class="ps-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ducimus commodi iure.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Dollar_Sign.svg/2048px-Dollar_Sign.svg.png" alt="">
        <p class="title-18-bold ps-4">Заявка</p>
        <small class="ps-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni suscipit fuga quidem corporis optio tempora sint debitis?</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>


</html>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: в качестве общего отступа попробуйте padding-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что это такой баг с тэгом `<small>`

0. Нажми ctrl+h
1. Выдели то где нужно исправить этот баг
2. Нажми In section
3. Введи small
4. Введи p
5. Нажми заменить

[image: Последовательность действий]

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать использовать `margin` для блока, вместо `padding`

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое свойство text-indent, как раз то что тебе нужно. Мой пример кода ниже.

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.text {
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(161, 101, 101);
  padding: 0 10px;
}

p {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
<div class='text'>
  <p>Что делать если после того как место для текста заканчивается и он переходит на новую строку отступ не сохраняется?
</p>
</div>
</div>
```